# Help identifying component on Sainsmart 4-Channel Relay board

Tags: relay

http://www.thesunrain.com/Amazon/4%20relay%20board/4-ch%20relay%20module.pdf

In the Schematic there are 4 Items Labeled U1,U3,U5,U7

They look like small black boxes on the actual boards. I can't really tell what they are, it looks like some sort of LED icon and then a transistor? If so whats their purpose? These are Mechanical Relays btw.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These components** are [opto-couplers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator).  Their purpose is to convey the digital signal while providing galvanic isolation.  If galvanic isolation is required, VCC and JD-VCC should come from separate power supplies, which are in turn isolated from each-other.

** U1, U3, U5, U7 in the [schematic](http://www.thesunrain.com/Amazon/4%20relay%20board/4-ch%20relay%20module.pdf).

Galvanic isolation is used to:

- stop high voltage events from getting into vulnerable areas
- block conducted EMI on the signal lines
- allow the isolated parts of the circuit to float with respect to each-other

## P.S.  critique of the schématique

For what it's worth, the schematic could have been drawn better.

- Isolated grounds should have different symbols to make it more obvious that there are isolate grounds in the circuit.  Isolation barrier should be drawn as a line.
- There are 2 connectors on the board with "J?" designators.
- It's better to have a separate power connector for each of the isolated sides.  Where's the ground pin for the right side power supply?
- No revision number.  No part number.

Comment: Are the optocouplers just for protection? I don't really understand their purpose? Is it so the connected relays don't backfeed some huge voltage back into the Arduino (or whatever microcontroller output pins i'd be using). Isn't that what the protection diode next to the relay is for?

Comment: @Mercfh  I've updated my post.  This is just an executive summary.  If you want to learn more about galvanic isolation, seek out the material on the web and read-up.

Comment: If memory serves me right, you can drive the relay from a separate power source. Separate from the logic input.